# Button To Add Text and a new line

Tags: ms-access, button, textbox, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to make a button in Microsoft Access 2010 with VBA to add pre-set text to a textbox and add a line break after the text. However, whenever I click the button it seems to be ignoring my `Then` statement and jumping right to the `Else` statement, adding a line break to the empty textbox and then adding the pre-set text no matter what the state of the *Notes* textbox is.

The submit button was originally an embedded macro but I have since converted it to VBA code in order to make my *Notes* textbox have no value to hopefully have my `Then` statement honored but with no luck. Here is the coding for both buttons:

```
Private Sub statusBtn_Click()
Notes.SetFocus
If Notes = "" Then Notes = "lorem ipsum" Else Notes = Notes & vbCrLf & "lorem ipsum"
Me![Notes].SelStart = IIf(IsNull(Me![Notes]), 0, Len(Me![Notes]))
End Sub



Private Sub SubmitBtn_Click()
On Error GoTo SubmitBtn_Click_Err
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
If (MacroError <> 0) Then
    Beep
    MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
End If
SubmitBtn_Click_Exit:
Exit Sub
SubmitBtn_Click_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume SubmitBtn_Click_Exit
Notes = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different form of your one-line `If ... Then` statement, which is easier for me to discuss:

```vb
If Notes = "" Then
    Notes = "lorem ipsum"
Else
    Notes = Notes & vbCrLf & "lorem ipsum"
End If
```

Consider the code path when *Notes* is Null.  The condition `Notes = ""` will not be True.  It won't be False, either, but that doesn't matter.  Since it's not True, control passes to the `Else` section.  And that means you concatenate Null plus CRLF (carriage return and line feed) plus *"loren ipsum"*.

I suspect you actually want *Notes* to become just *"loren ipsum"* whenever the starting value of *Notes* is either Null or an empty string (`""`).  In that case, change the `If` condition:

```vb
If Len(Notes & "") = 0 Then
```

Comment: Thank you very much Hans, you have resolved my issue!